# Change variable after x Seconds (Java)

Tags: java

i have the following code:

```
private boolean votesEnabled = false;
```

which is set at the beginning of my class.
On call of a certain action, I want to change the value from `false` to `true`

```
if (chatMessage.getText().equals("!newGame")) {
// change the value of votesEnabled for 90 seconds
}
```

Now, in two other cases, I have something like this:

```
if (chatMessage.getText().equals("!lose") && votesEnabled == true) {

    // check, if the person already placed a bet:
    if (!currentPlayers.contains(chatMessage.getName())) {

        // Add the name to the list of betters
        currentPlayers.add(chatMessage.getName());

        // write it in to the text-file
        try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(loserlist, true)))) {
            writer.println(chatMessage.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

... you get the idea.

Now my question: Do i have to extend the Thread-Class, to achieve that? A vote shall not be triggered, when 90 seconds (after !startGame) has passed. Is it doable without threads? Also, the variable has to be set to false after 90 secs again.

Quick Example

```
// Start => votesEnabled = false
// !newGame => votesEnabled = true
// 91 secs after !newGame => votesEnabled = false
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: No. Could be a console-app. No windows (or something similar)

Comment: A timer comes to mind. And no, you shouldn't ever extend Thread for anything. If you needed Threading, you'll almost always implement Runnable as any decent Threading tutorial will tell you.

Comment: I think if you put the logic into a method rather than a variable, you could do it without an extra thread: When you change it to true, save the current time. Then when you invoke the method, it checks whether the current time is less that 90 seconds from the previous.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment:

Instead of defining the variable `votesEnabled`, define:

```
private long lastVoteTimeMillis = 0L;
private static final long VOTE_PERIOD = 90000L;
```

Then define two methods:

```
private void enableVotes() {
    lastVoteTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

private boolean votesEnabled() {
    return System.currentTimeMillis() - lastVoteTimeMillis < VOTE_PERIOD;
}
```

Now you can do:

```
if (chatMessage.getText().equals("!newGame")) {
    enableVotes();
}
```

And then test using:

```
if (chatMessage.getText().equals("!lose") && votesEnabled() ) {
    // Do your vote-dependent stuff
}
```

This makes sure that your vote-dependent stuff will only be executed if less than 90 seconds passed since `!newGame`.

You can add flexibility to it. For example, you can make sure that a vote period can't be extended by checking first that you are not within a 90-second period, before setting `lastVoteTimeMillis` in `enableVotes()`. You can add a `disableVotes()` method that sets `lastVoteTimeMillis` to `0L` thus it will be more than 90 seconds in the next query.

This solution requires no additional threads at all, neither ones created by `Timer` nor extensions of `Thread` or `Runnable`. But if your game is already multithreaded, be sure to make the `lastVoteTimeMillis` variable `volatile`.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (chatMessage.getText().equals("!newGame")) {
// change the value of votesEnabled for 90 seconds
 votesEnabled = true;
 sleep(90000);
 votesEnabled = false;
}
```